# Where are Microsoft Outlook 2007 mails located?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

After a windows crash, I bought a new computer. I would like to recover the mails stored in the old install. I can access the old drive as a data disk, but windows won't boot anymore from it.

I've reinstalled everything on the new computer, but can't find my old emails. Where are they stored ?

Since I can't boot from the old drive, I cannot use Outlook's .pst export :(

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vista you should be able to find it in:
[WindowsDrive]:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook.

For instance:

C:\Users\Mano\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook.

Comment: It worked ! I was able to export the current mails into a pst file, copy the files in appdata, and then re-import that first pst file.
I now have my old and my recent mails.
Thanks !

Comment: Happy to help :)